# laravel error: rand() expects parameter 2 to be int, string

Tags: laravel, browser-cache

Facing error traying to run `php artisan serve` after clear and config cache on a laravel project `rand() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given (View: C:\Users\user\Desktop\traipler-fe\traipler-fe\resources\views\traipler\region\jscontainer.blade.php)`

jscontainer.blade.php

````
$cookie_uid =(\Cookie::get('tr_uid')?\Cookie::get('tr_uid'):'');
            if( $user = \Auth::user()){ 
              $cookie_uid = $user->id;
            }
            ('set', 'userId', 'USER_ID'); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
            if(empty($cookie_uid)){ //CREO UN COOKIED ID TEMPORANEO
              //$cookie_uid =  uniqid();
              $cookie_uid =  str_pad(rand(0,'9'.round(microtime(true))),11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
              Cookie::queue('tr_uid', $cookie_uid, 525600);
            }```
````

Comment: Instead of `round(microtime(true))` you can use `time()`. But your `rand()` works for me. Which PHP version and platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4.9 on wamp server

Answer (score 0):

You neew to convert 2nd param from string into an integer

```
$second_param = (int) '9'.round(microtime(true));
$cookie_uid =  str_pad(rand(0, $second_param),11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use int cast type or intval() function

```php
$int=(int) '9'.round(microtime(true)));
str_pad(rand(0,,11,$int, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

or

```php
$int=intval( '9'.round(microtime(true))));
str_pad(rand(0,,11,$int, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```